# Nodejs Google App Engine Logs Formatting

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, logging, app-engine-flexible

I have deployed a app to Nodejs environment on Google App Engine recently. Everything was fine till yesterday when the logs started to behave strangely. Earlier I could read the logs using a simple command

```
gcloud app logs read
```

Now the logs are being formated weirdly as given below

`2016-07-31 08:02:19 default[2]  <JsonPayloadValue   additionalProperties: [<AdditionalProperty   key: u'source'   value: <JsonValue   string_value: u'stdout'>>, <AdditionalProperty   key: u'container_id'   value: <JsonValue   string_value: u'67c934710ef37507a56ba3f00fd8d85cd977eb3d386caf6f7599acd9a2684c71'>>, <AdditionalProperty   key: u'log'   value: <JsonValue   string_value: u'Node app is running on port 8080'>>, <AdditionalProperty   key: u'container_name'   value: <JsonValue   string_value: u'/gaeapp'>>]>`

The only relevant part is `Node app is running on port 8080` but I am unable to figure out why its showing the whole dump kind of log in the output.

Comment: Well this is super weird.  Can you try running `gcloud app logs read --logs stdout`?  What does that look like?

Comment: @JustinBeckwith Same result with `gcloud app logs read --logs stdout` too

Comment: Ok, lets try one more :) What happens if you go the developers console and look at the logs in the UI?

Comment: And another question - how are you writing your logs?  Just console.log?  Winston?  Using gae-winston?

Comment: @JustinBeckwith The whole app is working is fine as such, so I cant see anythign except Success 200 in all the requests in console. I am using console.log directly.. Isn't it recommended? It was working fine just few days back.

Comment: Same problem here since 29 July, 17:11 CET. It looks like the app was restarted at that point and since then I get JSON instead of plain messages in the Stackdriver logs.

Comment: @Klemens , There was gcloud components update today, thought that would solve the issue, but nope it is still the same. Wondering what I did that would have caused this issue

Comment: @ChakradharReddyVeeramreddy Any updates here? The problem still exists on my side.

Comment: @Klemens Nope, it's still not resolved. I tried creating a whole new project and re initialized everything hoping it'll fix it, but no luck. Wondering if we are the only ones facing this issue

Comment: I submitted an issue by basically copying your text https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13220

Comment: From Google: "Thank you for bringing this to our attention. I have forwarded your report to the engineering team ..."

Comment: Great !! Hope they resolve it soon...

Comment: Seems to be fixed in my case, starting at 23:28 yesterday (CET). I can see in the logs that the node app was restarted.

Comment: Has this resurfaced? I'm noticing the same phenomenon.

Google Cloud SDK 271.0.0
bq 2.0.50
core 2019.11.08
gsutil 4.46

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. google-cloud-sdk-280.0.0